# What's the name of this function?

Tags: functions, notation

Does the function $f(x)=\log(-\log(x))$, $x\in(0,1)$ has a name? Equivalently, the function $g(y)=f^{-1}(y)=\exp(-\exp(y))$, $y\in{\mathbb R}$.

The only thing I want to know if whether this function is referred to with a particular name.

**EDIT.** The function $f$ is equivalent to the negative of the [quantile Gumbel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution#Quantile_function_and_generating_Gumbel_variates) (with location $0$ and scale $1$). Another user proposed to simply call it "Bob", the choice is yours.

Comment: I have never heard of a name for this particular function.

Comment: @Joel Could you please push your memory to the limit and post an answer?

Comment: Whatever it's called, its integral from 0 to 1 is $-\gamma$. (I would just call it "log-minus-log-x" or "log-minus-log," honestly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\log(-\log(x))$ is not in the standard canon of mathematical functions studied by most mathematicians. As far as I know, there is no name given to this function. If there is a name, then it is certainly not well known. The same is true for the exponential analogue of this function.

I hence declare this function's name to be Bob.

Comment: Bob sounds great.

Comment: Thank you for the pun. I just found that $f$ is the [Gumbel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution#Quantile_function_and_generating_Gumbel_variates) quantile function (with location $0$ and scale $1$). But yeah, Bob is has more personality.

Comment: I see. I liked Bob better, but I suppose Gumbel has a nice ring to it.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer just to give you some internet points. The answer I found is posted on my edited question.